# Safari, Mail and App Store won't open

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, safari, mail.app, crash

Some apps (Mail, Safari and App Store) crash when I try to start them. I have a Macbook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011, El Capitan). Also, the system often reboots due to kernel panics. To solve this, I recently reinstalled the system but after a few days problems reappeared. This is an example of the report shown when Mail crashes:

```
Process:               Mail [742]
Path:                  /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Identifier:            com.apple.mail
Version:               9.3 (3124)
Build Info:            Mail-3124000000000000~2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Mail [742]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2016-11-13 01:47:35.417 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1004)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D768F5FF-8D26-FC0F-7C82-FB524FF0A981

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DFBFF06C-F2C4-4EDE-BE57-6C844E89118A

Time Awake Since Boot: 5100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       19 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        24  Dispatch queue: com.apple.WebKit.ProcessLauncher

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001060ed000-00000001064a8000 [ 3820K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b4ef1 _CFBundleAddValueForType + 1
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b4cbc ___CFBundleReadDirectory_block_invoke + 524
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9577e3a1 _CFIterateDirectory + 849
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b44db _createQueryTableAtPath + 507
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b2b9b _copyQueryTable + 331
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b2372 _copyResourceURLsFromBundle + 370
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b18c6 _CFBundleCopyFindResources + 1206
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b1400 CFBundleCopyResourceURL + 64
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957b12a3 CFBundleGetLocalInfoDictionary + 83
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f727cb9 -[NSBundle localizedInfoDictionary] + 37
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f727c47 -[NSBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:] + 32
11  WebKit                          0x00007fff986966d0 WebKit::WebPageProxy::standardUserAgent(WTF::String const&) + 86
12  WebKit                          0x00007fff9889a4c1 WebKit::WebPageProxy::WebPageProxy(WebKit::PageClient&, WebKit::WebProcessProxy&, unsigned long long, WTF::Ref<API::PageConfiguration>&&) + 639
13  WebKit                          0x00007fff9889a22b WebKit::WebPageProxy::create(WebKit::PageClient&, WebKit::WebProcessProxy&, unsigned long long, WTF::Ref<API::PageConfiguration>&&) + 69
14  WebKit                          0x00007fff988efb31 WebKit::WebProcessProxy::createWebPage(WebKit::PageClient&, WTF::Ref<API::PageConfiguration>&&) + 55
15  WebKit                          0x00007fff988e66d2 WebKit::WebProcessPool::createWebPage(WebKit::PageClient&, WTF::Ref<API::PageConfiguration>&&) + 330
16  WebKit                          0x00007fff9893afd8 -[WKView initWithFrame:processPool:configuration:webView:] + 536
17  WebKit                          0x00007fff9869ff4b -[WKView(Private) initWithFrame:contextRef:pageGroupRef:relatedToPage:] + 211
18  WebKit                          0x00007fff986de862 -[WKView initWithFrame:processGroup:browsingContextGroup:] + 114
19  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff912bd401 -[MUIWKView initWithFrame:processGroup:browsingContextGroup:] + 103
20  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff912c2553 -[MUIWKViewController loadView] + 262
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a159a6 -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] + 75
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a15911 -[NSViewController view] + 30
23  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff912c2a7c -[MUIWKViewController view] + 39
24  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff912b58aa -[MUIWebDocumentView _muiWebDocumentViewCommonInitWithViewGroup:] + 142
25  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff912b573b -[MUIWebDocumentView initWithCoder:viewGroup:] + 116
26  com.apple.mail                  0x0000000106130c4c 0x1060ed000 + 277580
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a41e25 -[NSClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 568
28  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
29  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f7204fd -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1469
30  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f724d8c -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 203
31  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
32  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a4335e -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 2360
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89aaaaac -[NSClipView initWithCoder:] + 54
35  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
36  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f7204fd -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1469
37  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f724d8c -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 203
38  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
39  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
40  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a4335e -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 2360
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89aa98a3 -[NSScrollView initWithCoder:] + 266
42  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a41e25 -[NSClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 568
43  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
44  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f7204fd -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1469
45  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f724d8c -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 203
46  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
47  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
48  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a4335e -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 2360
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89d28879 -[NSStackView initWithCoder:] + 77
50  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
51  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a440ed -[NSResponder initWithCoder:] + 97
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a42a8f -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 105
54  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a511d3 -[NSCustomView initWithCoder:] + 79
55  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
56  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
57  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a440ed -[NSResponder initWithCoder:] + 97
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a42a8f -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 105
59  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89d28879 -[NSStackView initWithCoder:] + 77
60  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
61  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
62  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899913ec -[NSNibConnector initWithCoder:] + 68
63  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
64  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f7204fd -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1469
65  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f724d8c -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 203
66  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
67  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
68  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8998ff4e -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 200
69  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71f463 _decodeObjectBinary + 2743
70  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71e8a5 _decodeObject + 281
71  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89aa9551 -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 591
72  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89aa91f7 -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
73  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89aa848c -[NSViewController loadView] + 270
74  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a159a6 -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] + 75
75  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a15911 -[NSViewController view] + 30
76  com.apple.mail                  0x00000001061302b4 0x1060ed000 + 275124
77  com.apple.mail                  0x000000010621f2e7 0x1060ed000 + 1254119
78  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff9129ae2e -[MUICollectionView _faultCellsAtIndexesInRange:] + 1428
79  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff9129b123 -[MUICollectionView prepareContentInRect:] + 135
80  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a1808e8 -[NSView _updateSuggestedContentRectToValue:] + 729
81  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89bf76db -[NSView _updateSuggestedContentRect] + 100
82  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89c489b5 -[NSView _updateSuggestedContentRectForVisibleRectChange] + 219
83  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89af763b -[NSScrollView(NSRulerSupport) _handleBoundsChangeForSubview:] + 350
84  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89ab9412 -[NSView _postBoundsChangeNotification] + 132
85  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89ab9322 -[NSView translateOriginToPoint:] + 287
86  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89ab77f8 -[NSClipView _immediateScrollToPoint:] + 1964
87  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89ab6fa4 -[NSClipView scrollToPoint:] + 241
88  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89af4b40 -[NSScrollView scrollClipView:toPoint:] + 75
89  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a9c093 -[NSClipView _scrollTo:animateScroll:flashScrollerKnobs:] + 1692
90  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a9b821 -[NSClipView _reflectDocumentViewFrameChange] + 128
91  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899f891a -[NSView _postFrameChangeNotification] + 196
92  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899f36d3 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 2199
93  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff9129cf02 -[MUICollectionView setFrameSize:] + 105
94  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a0b90d -[NSView setFrame:] + 476
95  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff9129d93e -[MUICollectionView _updateGeometryIfNeeded] + 881
96  com.apple.MailUI                0x00007fff9129e7aa -[MUICollectionView scrollToCellAtIndex:constrainScroll:] + 576
97  com.apple.mail                  0x0000000106130206 0x1060ed000 + 274950
98  com.apple.mail                  0x000000010612f86d 0x1060ed000 + 272493
99  com.apple.mail                  0x000000010610ccc1 0x1060ed000 + 130241
100 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f754cab NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 379
101 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f7ceeba -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 1127
102 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89bb5af8 -[NSController _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 206
103 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89c07e13 -[NSArrayController didChangeValuesForArrangedKeys:objectKeys:indexKeys:] + 54
104 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89c09955 -[NSArrayController setContent:] + 768
105 com.apple.mail                  0x000000010610b219 0x1060ed000 + 123417
106 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f762314 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 424
107 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a2fb10 -[NSObjectParameterBinder _updateObject:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:] + 1498
108 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89a27761 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 758
109 com.apple.mail                  0x000000010612e7c2 0x1060ed000 + 268226
110 com.apple.mail                  0x000000010613f3ce 0x1060ed000 + 336846
111 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957febbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
112 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957feb4f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
113 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957feac7 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407
114 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957fe832 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
115 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957bb5e2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922
116 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957ba835 _CFXNotificationPost + 693
117 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f71517a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
118 com.apple.mail                  0x000000010613f04b 0x1060ed000 + 335947
119 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f7558d7 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
120 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f755595 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 100
121 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f753c7a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 654
122 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f74fc64 __NSOQSchedule_f + 194
123 libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3c840b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
124 libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3dbc1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1685
125 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff958289e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
126 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957e78dd __CFRunLoopRun + 1949
127 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957e6ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
128 com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff928ac935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
129 com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff928ac76f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
130 com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff928ac5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
131 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899ccdf6 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
132 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899cc226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
133 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899c0d80 -[NSApplication run] + 682
134 com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8998a368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
135 libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8c5a05ad start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.WebKit.ServicesController
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da41362 read + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95782a3f _CFReadBytesFromFile + 319
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95781509 CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource + 777
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95780e8c _CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryInDirectoryWithVersion + 812
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95780a75 CFBundleGetInfoDictionary + 69
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9577c9ea _CFBundleCreate + 1114
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f7182d2 -[NSBundle _cfBundle] + 73
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f727ca7 -[NSBundle localizedInfoDictionary] + 19
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f727c47 -[NSBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:] + 32
9   com.apple.ShareKit              0x00007fff91967ad2 +[SHKSharingService serviceDictionaryFromBundle:matchingUserDict:] + 75
10  com.apple.ShareKit              0x00007fff91968d9c +[SHKSharingService addServicesFromPlugIns:compatibleWithUserDict:toServices:] + 2025
11  com.apple.ShareKit              0x00007fff9196973b +[SHKSharingService sharingServicesWithIdentifier:attributes:matchingDictionary:attributeStore:invokedByPicker:] + 1885
12  com.apple.ShareKit              0x00007fff91969da5 +[SHKSharingService sharingServicesForItems:mask:invokedByPicker:] + 1096
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8999a83f +[NSSharingService sharingServicesForItems:mask:] + 69
14  WebKit                          0x00007fff987ea51f ___ZN6WebKit18ServicesController23refreshExistingServicesEb_block_invoke + 191
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3d393d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3c840b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cd03b _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3d3707 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3c840b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cc29b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cbb00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e1934de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da40efa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3ce165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cddcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

.
.
.

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da405e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e193578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da405e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e193578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13



.
.
. 

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da405e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e193578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da405e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e193578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 22:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.genius
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da39f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da393b3 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff94c262e9 mdsFetchCompleteSchemaInformation + 140
3   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff94c26151 _MDSchemaGetFullSchema + 48
4   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff94c260cc _MDCopyCompleteFlatSchema + 105
5   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff94c2a0b6 _MDSchemaCopyDisplayNameForCStringAttribute + 55
6   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff94c2a035 _MDSchemaCopyShortNamesForAttribute + 119
7   com.apple.Suggestions           0x00007fff8ba2d47e __41-[SGTQueryGenius initWithAttributeNames:]_block_invoke + 273
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3d393d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3c840b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cd03b _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3d3707 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3c840b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cc29b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cbb00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e1934de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da405e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e193578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 24 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.WebKit.ProcessLauncher
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c099132 strlen + 18
1   WebKit                          0x00007fff986c4683 WebKit::EnvironmentVariables::createStringForVariable(char const*, char const*) + 49
2   WebKit                          0x00007fff986c44f2 WebKit::EnvironmentVariables::set(char const*, char const*) + 62
3   WebKit                          0x00007fff986c62ab WebKit::addDYLDEnvironmentAdditions(WebKit::ProcessLauncher::LaunchOptions const&, bool, WebKit::EnvironmentVariables&) + 207
4   WebKit                          0x00007fff9869d1ed WebKit::ProcessLauncher::launchProcess() + 793
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8e1011d7 ___ZN3WTF9WorkQueue8dispatchENSt3__18functionIFvvEEE_block_invoke + 23
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3d393d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3c840b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cd03b _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3d3707 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cbd53 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 538
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e3cbb00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e1934de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Activity ID:             0x00000000000054bb
Activity Name:           sendAction:
Activity Image Path:     /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
Activity Image UUID:     F3411F6E-DD87-34D0-8C68-C69B2205E41D
Activity Offset:         0x002b1dbd
Activity Running Time:   1.994018 sec

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da405e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e193578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 26:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da405e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e193578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191341 start_wqthread + 13


.
.
.


Thread 30:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da39f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da393b3 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957e81c4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957e768c __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff957e6ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89b22d95 _NSEventThread + 149
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e19399d _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e19391a _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191351 thread_start + 13

Thread 31:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da4010a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c117d0f nanosleep + 199
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff8e98f020 std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) + 75
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8e11687b bmalloc::Heap::scavenge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 155
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8e1164d4 bmalloc::Heap::concurrentScavenge() + 68
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8e118a5a bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::entryPoint() + 90
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8e1189f9 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::pthreadEntryPoint(void*) + 9
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e19399d _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e19391a _pthread_start + 168
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191351 thread_start + 13

Thread 32:: com.apple.CoreAnimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da39f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8da393b3 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8beca8df CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 257
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8beca7d7 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e19399d _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e19391a _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e191351 thread_start + 13

Thread 24 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000013  rbx: 0x0000000000000013  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000008000  rbp: 0x0000700000bd5820  rsp: 0x0000700000bd5820
   r8: 0x000000010b7011c4   r9: 0x000000010b700000  r10: 0x00007fff76564e9e  r11: 0x000000010b7e2000
  r12: 0x0000700000bd5ab8  r13: 0x0000700000bd5968  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x00007fff989ab36c
  rip: 0x00007fff8c099132  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the Apple Hardware Test to see if you have a hardware problem? (for example faulty RAM)

Comment: In addition to the suggestion by @jksoegaard have you tried using your Mac in Safe Mode? You do this by holding the Shift key down during startup.

Comment: @jksoegaard I ran the Test a couple of months ago and the result was: "Alert: Apple Hardware Test has detected an error. 4Hdd/11/40000000:SATA(0,0)".  However, I've read this is not an issue.

Comment: I just erased the drive and reinstalled from a Time Machine copy. The problem persists. :(

Comment: @Alejandro Well, you need to run the test now. You cannot rely on a test from months ago - new hardware problems could come at any time.

Comment: @jksoegaard I changed the RAM and the kernel panics have stopped! I will do a clean install to see if the Apps are ok again. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I have seen it multiple times before where faulty RAM gives all sorts of weird errors and panics, including disk corruption unfortunately. I have created an answer for you here summarizing the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random crashes in known good apps combined with random kernel panics are often caused by hardware errors, typically faulty RAM.

Try doing an Apple Hardware Test to see if any hardware is shown as having problems.

You could also try booting from a USB-drive with a known-good copy of OS X to ensure that it is not software error.